# Selecting which NAs you want to consider in a multiplication in R

Tags: r, time, na, multiplication

I've tried to find a solution to my problem in other topics but I haven't found anything yet.

I have a data frame with some columns that I want to multiply. Col1 refers to how many times per week you exercise and Col2 refers to time spent every time you exercise.

```
  Col1  Col2
1 0     <NA>
2 3    00:40:00
3 2    00:40:00
4 5    00:20:00
5 <NA>   NA
6 0     <NA>
```

The first thing I need to do is to convert that time format in minutes or seconds. The second thing and the hard issue here is that, for the rows with at least one NA, in each row, the multiplication should only happen if the NA is present only in the second column( look at row 6 in this example). The result of the multiplication should be 0. On the other hand, if there's an NA in both columns it means those observations should be considered as 'missing' and return NA.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Try `library(lubridate); period_to_seconds(hms(df1$Col2))`

Comment: If the multiplication only happens when the second column is NA and it should be replaced by 0, then what kind of multiplication is it?  I think you wanted to multiply when both columns are not NA, when col2 is NA, you want 0 and when both are NA, it is NA?

Comment: Based on the conditions, may be `secs <- period_to_seconds(hms(df1$Col2));

i1 <- !is.na(df1$Col2);
df1$Secs[i1] <- secs[i1] * df1$Col1[i1];
df1$Secs[df1$Col1==0 & !i1] <- 0`

Comment: Just replace `NA`s in your second column with 0. Then you can multiply normally and get your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that's similar in spirit to @akrun's solution (in comments), but using the `replace` function and without using an additional `i1` indicator. First set up the data and do the conversion to seconds, per @akrun's pointer:

```
d <- data.frame(Col1 = c(0, 3, 2, 5, NA, 0),
                Col2 = c(NA, "00:40:00", "00:40:00", "00:20:00", NA, NA))
library(lubridate)
d$secs <- period_to_seconds(hms(d$Col2))
```

Now do the multiplication, and replace `NA`s in rows where `Col1==0` with `0`:

```
d$Col3 <- d$Col1 * d$secs
d$Col3 <- replace(d$Col3, d$Col1 == 0, 0)
# d$Col3[d$Col1 == 0] <- 0 # equivalent to above row
```

Result:

```
d
#   Col1     Col2 secs Col3
# 1    0     <NA>   NA    0
# 2    3 00:40:00 2400 7200
# 3    2 00:40:00 2400 4800
# 4    5 00:20:00 1200 6000
# 5   NA     <NA>   NA   NA
# 6    0     <NA>   NA    0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the strings to time object and then reconvert it to seconds with `period_to_seconds` (from `lubridate`).  Get the index of non-NA elements from 'Col2' ('i1'), Based on the index, create the 'Secs' column by multiplying with the corresponding elements of 'Col1' and assign values that are 0 in 'Col1' and is a NA in Col2 to 0

```
library(lubridate)
secs <- period_to_seconds(hms(df1$Col2))
i1 <- !is.na(df1$Col2)
df1$Secs[i1] <- secs[i1] * df1$Col1[i1]
df1$Secs[df1$Col1==0 & !i1] <- 0
df1
#  Col1     Col2 Secs
#1    0     <NA>    0
#2    3 00:40:00 7200
#3    2 00:40:00 4800
#4    5 00:20:00 6000
#5   NA     <NA>   NA
#6    0     <NA>    0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0L, 3L, 2L, 5L, NA, 0L), Col2 = c(NA, 
"00:40:00", "00:40:00", "00:20:00", NA, NA)), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```